Kustomize image replacement stops working after pushing changes to git
I have rather unusual issue with Kustomize and/or git.
I'm using kustomize with openshift and have following catalog structure:
├── bases
│   └── deployment.yaml
├── kustomization.yaml
└── overlays
    └── kustomization.yaml

Deployment is standard kubernetes' deployment with following values:
- name: example
  image: kustomize_image

and overlays/kustomization.yaml:
images:
- name: kustomize_image
  newName: repo/image_name
  newTag: tag

And when I run kustomize build ./ | oc apply --dry-run=client -o yaml -f - to check if the values are correctly applied it looks OK, deployment's image is replaces with repo/image_name:tag
BUT when I push those changes to remote git repository image substitution stops working. Instead of correctly assigned image:tag it leaves image: kustomize_image.
It works locally again when I change name of deployment and replicas: -name: in kustomization file.
This setup works correctly for other services that use the same setup. The only way I got this to work was hardcoding image in bases/deployment.yaml but it's not ideal as I want those values to be changed in CI/CD pipeline.
Edit:
Step by step:

Change newTag to new version
Run kustomize build ./ | oc apply --dry-run=client -o yaml -f - - output is correct, image is changed to repo/name:tag
Commit and push changes to repository.
After changes are pushed run kustomize build ./ | oc apply --dry-run=client -o yaml -f - again and image in deployment.yaml is kustomize_image instead of repo/name:tag. Same happens in openshift cluster - image value is kustomize_image


I don't understand what the problem is. BUT when I push those changes to remote git repository image substitution stops working what does this mean? Can you show us your pipeline?

What I mean is before I push any changes to repo it builds correctly (kustomize build) with image tag. When I commit and push those changes and then try to build it locally (kustomize build), the image is not changed and remains kustomize_image

Managed to fix it.
It had nothing to do with git or Kustomize but with Application config in ArgoCD.
In my config I used:
source:
  directory:
    jsonnet: {}
    recurse: true

which doesn't consider overlays and bases directories but includes files from the root of the configured repository/ path.
Solution was to change Application configuration to:
source:
  path: .
  repoUrl: url
  targetRevision: branch

